# Какие реализации табов лучше использовать? Насколько грамотен этот код?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

[код на codepen](https://codepen.io/Houl-Holife/pen/bGdZKgb)

```
    'use strict'
    let tabLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.tb-links a'),
    tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('.tb-content div')
tabs.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    event.preventDefault();
    if(target.tagName != 'A') return false;

    for (let i of tabLinks){
        i.classList.remove('active');
    }
    for (let i of tabContents){
        i.classList.remove('show');
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < tabLinks.length; i++) {
        if(tabLinks[i] == target){
            tabLinks[i].classList.add('active');
                tabContents[i].classList.add('show');
        }
    }


});
```

Comment: Что здесь может быть, назначает класс `active` активной вкладке и `show` содержимому соответствующей вкладки. Все остальное в `css`, подход вполне себе правильный, разделение функционала между JS и CSS.

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info , а затем добавьте метку [инспекция-кода], нажав [edit]